# ngrx highlight newly added item in grid

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am using ngrx(redux) and I have a list of items displayed (virtual scrolling).
On click of a toolbar add button I dispatch Add action and reducer adds one more object to the list and returns new state.

How do I highlight the newly created row?

Should I keep in state a new property with id of the record which is created newly? I might have to scroll the newly created item in view also. Because as the list is virtually scrolled, the component may get destroyed and recreated if user is scrolling the list.

Comment: can you create a plunker to reproduce?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, set isHighlighted to true for the one that just got created.  Assuming that you are using something like reselect.js to write your selectors you can then map this list to your Item [dumb component](http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-smart-components-vs-presentation-components-whats-the-difference-when-to-use-each-and-why/).

Then in your Item dumb component if isHighlighted is true then you would highlight.

In terms of the extra complexity that will happen with virtual scrolling, the Store shouldn't care about dom elements getting destroyed or recreated.  Therefore if your highlighted Item component gets removed from the dom, that item should still stay in the Store.

Comment: keeping it in store would mean that the item is forever highlighted, till user takes some other action and which is processed by reducer, may be.  Also if i have to scroll the item to view, at what point should that be done?  At present i am keeping the id of new created item separately in store and have added a selector for that field.  Whenever the value changes i scroll grid to that record.  This also has problem as the selector gets fired even before the grid is fully rendered!!